# UV texture with problems when joining one mesh to another

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I would like to know if I can solve this problem:
I'm editing a character in which his body is covered by an image texture, but the character has separate body parts (leg, arm, etc.), whenever I try to unite the parts with ctrl-j, the mesh loses its UV configuration.

Is there any way to join the meshes without losing the UV mapping that came with it?

In image 1, it is the character with the mapping that came with it and that I would like to use, in 2 it is when I joined the meshes and it already lost the mapping and in 3, it is the mapping that is made from the union of the meshes , but it is bad, because the image was made for the default mapping.

Thanks!

(I want to unite the parts, because when I change his pose, the separated parts form a hole)

Edit: I'm sending the file to anyone who wants to take a look, but it's NSFW

[Archives](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1QkDRAG3d7jUn3gFtRQmoRRP2qB_EwyQk?usp=sharing)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello could you please pack the images and share the file?

Comment: This sure is a behaviour that shouldn't happen. You might try pinning all vertices in the UV editor (press P). Also make sure you don't have live unwrap or auto unwrap enabled

Comment: I tried to join the parts with the uv editor vertices fixed, but it ends up changing too.  live unwrapping is not enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the exact same name to the UV maps of both the 2 objects before joining, join and it should work, otherwise the 2 UV maps will stay separate:

[image]